# HTC Desire X doesn't come up after software upgrade

Tags: htc-desire

*I want to apologize in advance if this isn't the proper forum for my question; it might be a hardware problem.*

I got a message on my HTC Desire X that a software upgrade was available. (IIRC I was on 4.1) I checked if there was enough juice in the battery, enabled WiFi, and downloaded the upgrade. But when I clicked "install" the display simply went black, and the device hasn't given any signs of life since.

**What I tried**
1. Remove and re-insert the battery
2. Recharge the battery. This shouldn't have been necessary, since it had enough power, like I said. But strangely, even after 24h of charging the power LED remains orange
3. Factory reset: volume down + power button

The battery thing bugs me. It was a good battery (normal charging times) and now it doesn't work anymore. Does the charger rely in the CPU? For instance, if the upgrade really went bad and the CPU doesn't work properly, what about charging.

*IF* the upgrade didn't succeed, is there a way to get the device working again?

Comment: Does the device waken when plugged in? Maybe try booting it in Safe or Force Restart it. Was it rooted?

Comment: It isn't rooted. And no, it doesn't wake up at all, not even when plugged in. So how can I boot in Safe or Force Restart (whatever that means)?

Comment: Hold down the power an volume up button try that

Comment: @user68932 - Yes, I even tried that. (Though the documented factory reset is with the volume down button)